# Copy program to SD card before boot

Tags: boot, sd-card

I'd like to "install" a programm on the Pis SD card before I instert it into the Pi and ideally configure it to run after boot.

When I insert the SD card into my PC, all I can see is the boot folder, I don't know where to put my files.

Basically, what I want to do is prepare a SD card with Raspbian and my own program configured to start on boot before it has ever been in the Pi.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=231762

Comment: Thank you, I think this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to easily change Raspbian by modifying the boot sector (e.g. including `ssh` etc).

To perform more complex actions (such as adding programs) is possible, but requires a Linux computer and involves quite a few steps.

It is questionable whether this is worthwhile for a one-off installation, but is effective to make a custom image for use by others.

The excellent [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=231762) explains one method in detail.

NOTE This does **NOT** allow the installation of software (but you can modify configuration files etc.) - the techniques to allow this effectively require building a new image.

Comment: Thank you :) 
Well yes, I was hoping I could simply put a SD card with my own program installed into the Raspberry Pi and boot it up. Since I don't have another linux around and installing a VM just do to this would be overkill I will just install it traditionally (boot up, copy files, etc...).
But thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: The link is dead.